# Default for step-by-step editing in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

[image]

I've done the extra in vuejs. Now I do the editing , But have some problems.

```
// edit
b-button
  v-ripple.400="'rgba(113, 102, 240, 0.15)'"
  title="Edit"
  variant="outline-danger"
  class="btn-icon "
  :to="{ name: 'user-edit', params: { id: props.row.id } }"
 ></b-button>
```

I want when I go to the edit page, it will be in step two **Personal Info** instead of step one **Account Details**.

Below is the code I process step by step

```
<div class="user-setting">
      <form-wizard
        color="#7367F0"
        :title="'User Setting'"
        :subtitle="'Setting the user by yourself'"
        finish-button-text="Submit"
        back-button-text="Previous"
        next-button-text="Netx"
        class="wizard-vertical mb-3"
        @on-complete="formSubmitted"
      >
        <!-- Account Details -->
        <tab-content
          title="Account Details"
          :before-change="() => validate('firstStep')"
        >
          <b-row>
            <b-col cols="12" class="mb-2">
              <h5 class="mb-0">Account Details</h5>
              <small class="text-muted"> Enter Your Account Details </small>
            </b-col>
          </b-row>
          <campaign-type
            ref="firstStep"
            v-on:user-type-change="userSetting($event)"
            @on-validate="onStepValidate"
          />
        </tab-content>

        <!-- Personal Info -->
        <tab-content
          title="Personal Info"
          :before-change="() => validate('secondStep')"
        >
          <b-row>
            <b-col cols="12" class="mb-2">
              <h5 class="mb-0">Personal Info</h5>
            </b-col>
          </b-row>
          <discount-cut-off ref="thirdStep"
            @on-validate="onStepValidate"
            :offerOptions="offerOptions" v-if="cutoff"/>
          <promotion-object v-else
            ref="secondStep"
            @on-validate="onStepValidate"
            :offerOptions="offerOptions"
          />
        </tab-content>
      </form-wizard>
    </div>
```

Let me know your ideas. Thanks.